# SRWebsocket close the connection ios

Tags: ios, socketrocket

I am using SRWebsocket in my connection class I am trying to disconnect the socket when the app goes to background i have tried these things

```
SRWebSocket *_webSocket;


-(void)close

{


    [_webSocket close];
    _webSocket.delegate = nil;
    _webSocket = nil;


}
```

but it is not closing the socket please help me in doing so .

Comment: Did you make sure this code gets called ? Put a breakpoint there and see if it really executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that, if you nil the websocket delegate at this point, when the socket actually closes (it's not inmediate), there will be no delegate to process the `webSocket:diCloseWithCode:` event. But the socket should certainly be closed anyway.

It may not be that, but it would make more sense to just send the close message. Then wait for the didClose and there, you can nil both the delegate and the actual _websocket.